# How to call method from a different form to be used in a second form when a button is clicked

Tags: c#

```
//now i want the label in this method to be displayed when a button is clicked in the second form

public void display()
{
    cityVar = cities;
    dateVar = Date;
    min_TempVar = MinTemp; 
    maxTempVar = MaxTemp;
    precipitationVar = precipitation;
    humidityVar = humidity;
    windSpeedVar = Wind;

    // ReportForm rf = new ReportForm(); i am calling the second form
    // rf.Display_Label.Text  is a label in the Report form 

    rf.Display_Label.Text = string.Format(@"
    Weather forecast for {0} 
    for the  {1}
    ------------------------------------------
    min temp: {2} C
    max temp: {3} C
    precipitation: {4} %
    humidity: {5} % 
    wind speed:{6} km/h ",
    cityVar, dateVar, min_TempVar, maxTempVar, precipitationVar, 
    humidityVar,windSpeedVar);

}

//this how i did it but it does not seem to work , can someone please assist me in the correct way to do this
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //  WeatherApp form = new WeatherApp(); calls the first form
    WeatherApp form = new WeatherApp();
    // form.display() should call the Public void display method which is in the WeatherApp form 
    form.display(); 
}
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: my apology . this is my first time posting question here

Comment: It doesn't look like your code would compile. For instance some of your last lines of code include `WeatherApp form` followed up `form.display();`. You need a semi colon after your declaration of `form` and then calling `form.display()` right after would result in a null reference exception during runtime... if your compiler even let you compile it. I would remove the `WeatherApp form` line of code. You already define that var in the statement `WeatherApp form = new WeatherApp();`

Comment: [Call a method from another form](//stackoverflow.com/q/12890754)

Comment: benhorgen please elaborate more when you  say "You need a semi colon after your declaration of form"